InDesign: FPO placment ontop of graphic that has Text Wrap
I have a layout where a graphic has text wrap attached to it.
I need to put an FPO over it, but the text wrap pushes the FPO text away.
I tried to put the FPO text in another layer above, but that didn't work either. Any solutions for this specific problem? (Besides turning it off and manually break the lines of the textblock next to it?)


Select the text frame for "FPO" using the Selection Tool
Choose Object > Text Frame Options (Command/Ctrl+b)
Tick the Ignore Text Wrap box near the bottom of that dialog window.
Hit OK

You can actually bring up the text frame options at any time when the frame is active. Whether it's highlighted with a Selection tool or even if the text cursor is inside the frame blinking. I tend to just Command+b at any point when I need it - even in the process of typing in the text frame.
(Image from older InDesign version, but the option is in essentially the same location for more recent versions.)

The frame for "FPO" will no longer see or care that there's a text wrap anywhere.
